# JIRA Plugin communicate with Confluence

Tags: jira, confluence, jira-plugin, confluence-rest-api

Is it possible to communicate directly with Confluence to search / add pages to space etc from a custom Jira plugin?

I currently have a Jira plugin I'm working on which displays a panel in the issue viewer but want to search for a particular page in confluence to display a link to it if it exists.  If it doesn't exist I want to have a button which allows the user to create that page.

I have looked at the REST API and it looks like it should do what I want, but can I interact directly using the JAVA classes?

Does the single sign on between them allow me to call a REST service on confluence from JIRA without putting authentication into the REST call?

Answer (score 4):

**In short:**

> I have looked at the REST API and it looks like it should do what I want, but can I interact directly using the JAVA classes?

No. There is no java api available as simple as:

```
ConfluenceService.searchPage(String title)
ConfluenceService.createPage(String parent, String title)
```

> Does the single sign on between them allow me to call a REST service on confluence from JIRA without putting authentication into the REST call?

Yes.

**In more detail:**

The java api's that you can use are the [Application Link api](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/atlassian-platform-common-components/application-links) and the [SAL api](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/atlassian-platform-common-components/shared-access-layer/sal-services), especially Request and Response from the [com.atlassian.sal.api.net](https://docs.atlassian.com/sal-api/3.0.6/sal-api/apidocs/index.html?com/atlassian/sal/api/net/Request.html) package.

What it comes down to is that you first configure an application link in JIRA to your Confluence instance. Then from within your custom plugin, you use the application link api to retrieve an ApplicationLink instance, e.g.:

```
ApplicationLink confluenceLink = applicationLinkService.getPrimaryApplicationLink(ConfluenceApplicationType.class)
```

After that you can use this *confluencelink* to get a requestFactory:

```
ApplicationLinkRequestFactory requestFactory = confluenceLink.createAuthenticatedRequestFactory();
```

The requestFactory makes it easy to send REST requests to Confluence and handle the responses. It also takes care of the authentication, using the configuration from the application link in JIRA.

For a more detailed example, including searching for Confluence pages, check [this tutorial](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/guides/other/tutorial-application-links-in-jira).

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, it may also be worth to look at the [Structure](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.almworks.jira.structure/server/overview) and [Structure Pages](https://wiki.almworks.com/display/pages/Structure.Pages+Quick+Start+Guide) add-ons. Their goal is to integrate JIRA and Confluence more tightly and provide a user friendly way to display Confluence pages in Structures within JIRA and edit those pages from within JIRA.

Answer (score 0):

Jira has something called the JRJC: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.jira-rest-java-client/server/overview

This isn't actively supported by Atlassian, but it might do what you need.

But rather than limiting yourself to JRJC, I would suggest you use Jersey or whatever and simply use the REST APIs directly

I have had good luck having Jira and Confluence interact with each other using The REST APIs, jq, and bash scripts.

Here is a blog I wrote about it, which contains a github location for the source.
https://javamemento.blogspot.no/2016/05/jira-confluence-3.html

The script is in bash, but it might give you some insight into how to use it from java. I have not worked with searching on confluence for pages, however.

As for your last question, no, you will need to provide authentication with each REST call.